# Ui-Grid Not Displaying (at all)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm using AngularJS. The controller is functioning; I can call functions and values from it via my view. I can assign values to my gridOptions.data without console error. I can define other properties for gridOptions without conosole error. But the grid doesn't display... at all.

My index.html has the following header:

```
<!--Lib-->
    <!--jquery-->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
            <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>-->
        <!--ng base-->
            <script src="app/lib.bower/angular/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="app/lib.bower/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>   
        <!--ui grid-->
            <script src="app/lib.bower/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js"></script>
            <link href="app/lib.bower/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!--Misc-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/lib.bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
            <script src="app/lib.bower/toastr/toastr.js"></script>
            <link href="app/lib.bower/toastr/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--Custom-->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <!--Custom - Services-->
    <script src="app/services/resetRequestService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/adValidationService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/userSearchService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/passwordCreationService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/toasterService.js"></script>
    <!--Custom - Controllers-->
    <script src="app/controllers/UserSearchController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/HeaderController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/PasswordResetRequestController.js"></script>
    <!--Custom modules-->
    <script src="app/modules/header.js"></script>
    <!--Custom - Other-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/passwordReset.css"/>
```

My controler is as such:

```
var userSearchController = function($scope, $interval, userSearchService) {
var vm = this;

vm.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    showGridFooter: true,
    data: [
        {
            test: 'test',
            test2: 'test2'
        }
    ]
};
//more code

}
```

And the view has the following div:

```
<div ui-grid="vm.gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

Again, I don't get any errors, I just get... nothing on my .html; no data, no columns, not even a border, it *entirely* doesn't appear. I've ensured that the vm.gridOptions is assigned as soon as the controller starts up, and (again) I've ensured that I can run methods and get values from my controller.

I've poured over numerous tutorials which all have their own flavor of making ui-grid work, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: I see you're using the dot notation with "vm" which implies you've used the ControllerAs pattern, something like "UserSearchController as vm" either in the view or routing.  Is that correct?

Comment: @jbrown Yep, in the syntax of `controller: 'UserSearchController as vm',`. I'm fairly certain that part is plumbed up correctly as I can call functions stored to 'vm' via the view and `ng-click="vm.function()"`, and get values via the syntax `{{vm.valueName}}`.

Comment: Did you add it as a dependency? (ex: var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid']) )

Comment: @BrianS Thank you, Brian. That was it. A stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: :) I still do that, far too often..